# Javascript submit form not getting submitted in Firefox and IE

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am submitting a form in javascript to a controller in C# MVC it submits easily in chrome but not in Firefox and IE

```
//CSHTML CODE    
<th class="gen2">
   <button type="button" id="buttonClass">Generate</button>
</th>
<td class="money"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="checkboxID"    value=@item.WithdrawalID></td>


    //Javascript code
        $("#buttonClass").click(function () {
            getValueUsingClass();
        });
        function getValueUsingClass() {
            var data = "";
            var submitForm = document.createElement('form'); 

   //Creating a form and giving the attributes
            submitForm.name = "formSubmit";
            submitForm.id = "formSubmit";
            submitForm.method = "post";
            submitForm.action = "generatebankfile";
            var chkArray = \[\];
            alert(chkArray);
            $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
                chkArray.push($(this).val());
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < chkArray.length; i++) {
                data = data + chkArray\[i\];
                if (i != chkArray.length - 1) {
                    data = data + ',';
                }
            }
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.name = "checkboxID";
            element.value = data;
            submitForm.appendChild(element);

            if (chkArray.length > 0) {
                submitForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select at least one of the checkbox");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create a `form` and submit it? You can use ajax to post data to any `Action` method. You are any ways constructing the contents that need to be posted. Just stringify them and send it to the action. I know this is not an answer to your question, just thought it would be better way.

Comment: Looks like you're not appending the newly created form to the page. Try also to append the form.

Comment: any error in firefox console.. ?

Answer (score 1):

append form to the body

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(submitForm);

Comment: `document.body.append(...)` would do the same ; ).